# Using Ancestors in App Engine Mobile Backend Starter for Android

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am attempting to build off of the App Engine MSB. The client it comes with handles a simple public single-thread messaging application through a general backend. I want to extend the client to build a "real" messaging app. By that I mean that I would like a user to be able to have multiple private conversations.

I'm new to Google Cloudstore, but through discussions I thought having a message entity for each message made sense, and then setting the ancestor of the message to be the conversation it belongs to would make sense. And then a user would have a list of referenceProperties to the conversations it was involved in.

As I look at the Mobile Backend Starter I see that the android client doesn't actually create any entities itself. It uses a shell class "CloudEntity" to hold data and then pass it over the Google Endpoints api to the general server code which will built an Entity and insert it in the cloud store. (with intermediary steps through EntityDto?) My understanding is that the ancestor key needs to be available at the time the Entity is created, as it becomes part of the key for the entity, so if there was a way I could modify the android client code for CloudEntity to handle the ancestor that would be great.

I've looked at code for the [client](https://github.com/hoovercj/solutions-mobile-backend-starter-android-client) and the [server](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/solutions-mobile-backend-starter-java/) and it's a lot to take in, so I was hoping I could get some assistance:

1) Is it possible with the MBS client code to set ancestors for entities?
2) Is it even desirable to want to use ancestors in this way?

This is my first question, so thank you for your time and patience.